# PlatformException(authorize_and_exchange_code_failed)

Tags: flutter, authentication, bloc, appauth

In first time when I login give me this error:
**PlatformException(authorize_and_exchange_code_failed, Failed to authorize: The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.openid.appauth.general error -3.), null, null)**.
I used **flutter_appauth** package, for what it can be?

I want to know for what is it and how to fix.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found for what is that it is because I called log in event twice, I fixed it)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).